# How to control the scope of a PowerShell scriptblock

Tags: powershell, closures, scriptblock

I have a function written in PowerShell:

```
function replace([string] $name,[scriptblock] $action) {
    Write-Host "Replacing $name"
    $_ = $name
    $action.Invoke()
}
```

and would be used as:

```
$name = "tick"
replace $agentPath\conf\buildAgent.dist.properties {
    (cat templates\buildAgent.dist.properties.tpl) `
        -replace '@@serverurl@@', 'http:/localhost:8080/teamcity' `
        -replace '@@name@@', $name `
        > $_
}
```

However I've discovered that within the scriptblock the variable `$name` is overwritten by the `$name` param from within the `replace` function.

Is there a way to execute the script block so that only the variable `$_` is added to the scope of the scriptblock but nothing else is?

Answer (score 1):

I preface my answer by claiming that powershell is only for sadists. The trick is that if you put the function into a module the local variables become private and are not passed to the script block. Then to pass in the `$_` variable you have to jump some more hoops.

The `gv '_'` get's the powershell variable `$_` and passes it to the context via `InvokeWithContext`.

Now I know more than I ever wanted to :|

```
New-Module {
    function replace([string] $name,[scriptblock] $action) {
        Write-Host "Replacing $name"
        $_ = $name
        $action.InvokeWithContext(@{}, (gv '_'))
    }
}
```

and as before

```
$name = "tick"
replace $agentPath\conf\buildAgent.dist.properties {
    (cat templates\buildAgent.dist.properties.tpl) `
        -replace '@@serverurl@@', 'http:/localhost:8080/teamcity' `
        -replace '@@name@@', $name `
        > $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `$global:` *prefix* for the `$name` variable within your *scriptblock*:

```
$name = "tick"
replace $agentPath\conf\buildAgent.dist.properties {
    (cat templates\buildAgent.dist.properties.tpl) `
        -replace '@@serverurl@@', 'http:/localhost:8080/teamcity' `
        -replace '@@name@@', $global:name `
        > $_
}
```

Comment: I could but that is asking for me or another developer to forget one day and the problem randomly appears in the future. I'd expect there to be some kind of solution working from the other end where the caller of the script block is polite and doesn't inject all their local variables into the scope.

Comment: I found a way to do it. It's ugly for sure :) See my answer.

Comment: It looks ugly but I agree that its better for other developer *using* the function.